# criação de web server

Tags: aplicação-web, servidor

Boa tarde

Gostaria de pedir apoio de como criar um web server num computar pessoal e com fazer que um site esteja acessível a qualquer um e não apenas através do localhost

Obrigado

Comment: Wamp, Xampp ou Lampp + IP Fixo ou No-IP (e similares).

Answer (score 1):

Se sua intenção é ter um servidor web para colocar um site no ar com custos reduzidos. Será melhor fazer mais como experiência ou curiosidade.

A instalação do Apache Web ou Nginx em sua máquina e uma conta no site https://www.noip.com/ já são o suficiente para colocar um site no ar, mas com ressalvas.

Vc depende de taxa de Upload alto, pois seus usuários estarão baixando seu site e links domésticos de internet prezam mais por taxas de download mais altas do que Upload (seus usuários terão que ser pacientes...)

O site noip.com é um freemium, ou seja, logo precisará pagar para ter mais recursos.

Recomendo pesquisar por hospedagem de sites!
Mas como uma simples experiência ou curiosidade, boa sorte com seu projeto!